# New NextJS project not displaying images

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page located here: `project/pages/index.js`
The under `project/images/logo.png`

Now in my index.js i have this `<img src="/images/logo.png" />` however I get a 404

How do I use images in NextJs?

My next.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must put image in Public folder and in Src img write "/logo.png"

if you work on Nextjs , stady [Image/Next](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)